# How to pass values to phaser (Dart port) State.init() function?

Tags: dart, phaser-framework

I have the beginnings of my game code structured like this

```dart
main() {
new Foo();
}

class Foo {

GameMap map;

Foo() {
  map = new GameMap(32, 32); //GameMap is a class of my own
  ... // do some map-related initialisation
  Game game = new Game(800, 600, AUTO, 'canvasDiv');
  State state, state2; 
  state = new FileWaitState(); //explained below
  game.state.add('wait', state);
  game.state.start('wait');
  state2 = new MapRenderState();
  game.state.add('maprender', state2);
}
```

So, the idea with `FileWaitState` is that an algorithm needs to run to analyse a text file submitted by the user/player and until that analysis is complete my second state, currently called `MapRenderState` must not start. To facilitate this `FileWaitState` has in its `update()` function a check to see if the file has been given, and if it has it starts the async. function call to analyse the file, which has a `.then()` chained onto it like

```dart
.then(_) {
  game.state.start('maprender');
}
```

Now, my problem is that because the instance of my `FileProcessor` which I must call the analysis function on is nested inside `GameMap`, I want a way to pass a reference to the map from `Foo` constructor into `FileWaitState`. (Sort of an aside: and even if somehow or for some reason I was to restructure code so that I wouldn't need a map reference here, if possible, I will have the same kind of problem for `MapRenderState`.) I have seen that Phaser's `State` has an `init()` function which is the first thing to be called on a newly started state, and it allows for a variable amount of args to be passed into it. What I was trying to figure out though is how am I supposed to specify what args are to be passed into it, or if I'm approaching this wrongly? Surely there is a way to send values in there, right? Otherwise what's the point of init() allowing any args? I don't mean declaring what it's supposed to take; obviously I just need to write my init implementation in whatever State class. I mean, going back to my code, if I say init is to take one arg of type `GameMap` then is there a way to say somewhere "when calling init for this State, pass in this GameMap [from Foo ctor] as the arg"

I apologise if there is something basic about the framework that I am missing here but even after looking through some of the original Phaser.js API docs (since the dart port docs aren't all complete yet) I haven't figured out what I could do to get this working. I guess there's also the fact that I'm a bit "under the weather" at the moment so I don't feel up for doing a lot of programming work right now but at the same time I have put some of this work off a bit too long so I would like to get this code roadblock out of the way so that I have something less demotivating to work on for this project.

**TL;DR attempt**

I have a State (FileWaitState) and want to pass a reference to a GameMap into its init() function because the State's update function will need to access GameMap data. My problem is that this code

`map.fileProcessor.analyseTxtFile(ie.files[0])`
in the update func gives the error
`The null object does not have a getter fileProcessor` or so because obviously I haven't passed in a reference to the GameMap to make the `map` var *inside* the state not null. My question is how am I supposed to pass that reference in?

Comment: Thanks for the question! Can you make a tldr version? It's hard to tell what exactly you're asking (there's a lot of commentary in here :)  Try to rewrite your question in a very clear way, and include errors that you're getting. You can even use pseudo-code to explain what you want to do.

Comment: Hi, I shall try making a TLDR now..but oh yes I did forget the error. The error I get is from trying to call functions on null object, because of my issue of not being able to pass in a map reference into my state init function.

Comment: I think it is quite optimistic to expect an answer to such a question. It seems that what you want to do/know is quite basic but the explanation refers so many things that it seems it is necessary to look up how the framework works to even understand the question. 
I suggest you try to simplify/clarify the question and also to create an issue in the framework repo with a link to this question to make the developer aware of you problem (isn't sure he/she is monitoring SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but if you want to pass something to initialize a state, you can do that in the constructor of the state. For example your state constructor could be

`MapRenderState(this.map){//do something about map}`

Then you can do

```
game.state.add('render',new MapRenderState(map));
game.state.start('render');
```

If you want to load a map in a state and use the map in the same state, do the loading in *preload()* . I recommend using phaser's loading function. `game.load.text(key,url)` will load a text file.

Comment: Oh yes, I think this will suit me fine indeed. I can't believe I didn't think to just make constructors with the `GameMap` arg.. :( Maybe I thought I would be allowed to, who knows :/ Since I suppose you have at least some experience with Phaser though, can I ask how is the init function actually supposed to be used then? I mean, as demonstrated by my question I really can't see how you're supposed to pass values into it. Since the calling of State functions is handled by `StateManager` how do you set what _values_ are to be passed into it?

Comment: One other thing: yeah I have used that text loading code in another part of this code already so I had seen that but in the part I was describing for my problem it is not appropriate because the text file analysis the code will do will be used in a way to determine how parts of the "map" to render later will look; the text itself is not being put to the screen in this case. Thanks for the help and advice anyway :)

Comment: I'm also quit new to this library and I never used init. I'm also making a tilemap game(wip), what I will do about the map is, I will have a variable in the state object. You can assign any map to this variable before you start the  state, so that you can use the map in state's update function. This way you don't need to make multiple state objects for different maps. This might not be the best practice though.